# Getting CORS error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cors, angularjs-http

I am trying to hit an https based API, which is successfully working in POSTMAN and other REST client, but not in my AngularJS app.

Following is the code -

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://agXXXXX.com/api/contact/',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    data: user,
    withCredentials: true
};
$http(req)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log("--Data--");
        console.log(data);
    })
```

After following few stack CORS related article, I also included this in `.config()`, but no luck -

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"};
```

Following is the error I am facing -

[image: Cors Error]

Let me know what I am doing wrong, or missing here.

Comment: The browser is not going to let your JavaScript code access that URL unless its server is responding with the access control header that would allow it to do so.

Comment: I don't think you can use $http if its a https call. Test it out by keeping your code the same but try hitting an open source http.

Comment: @JoeLloyd it's not an `http` vs. `https` issue unless the origin domain is the same, and the page attempting the access is not `http` but the service is.

Comment: @Pointy Please check the screenshot as Server is responding with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Comment: @JoeLloyd It is not a case of http

Comment: add custom header to web.config file in <system.webServer> tag to allow Cross-Domain Request (CORS).                                                                    `<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>` try this

Comment: Hmm well the only thing that looks funny to me is that the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header is all lower-case, but I'm not sure that makes a difference.

Comment: @Pointy oh my gosh..seems you pointed me in a right direction..let me chk

Comment: @TechSolvr well it may be worth a try, but I think it's not supposed to make a difference.

Comment: @Pointy ok..I will ask the server person to correct it..once done I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

If you just need test your app you can use this chrome plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

But if you need this in production, you need config your server. If you are using SPRING:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

Comment: That will not help if the server won't accept cross-domain requests.

Comment: @Ivan are you sure that the plugin will help me as I previously mentioned that I am going to hit the API successfully from POSTMAN/ REST client ?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. But this isnt a solution, just a patch. You need config your server

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your server code headers to enable cors.

in this site you could read about it, and get code to implement it depending on the language in your backend:

http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: TL;DR Can you please check the screenshot and let me know which header is missing ?

Comment: Hmm. it seems like you added that header. maybe you added it with a typo?